# How to generate keys after creating user with adduser --disabled-password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

On a remote server I want to create a normal user and ONLY allow access via a key but I do NOT want to create the account with a password first and then disable password access later. In my admin account on the remote server I have done the following:

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password normaluser
```

Trying to connect as 'normaluser' is rejected, as desired with:

> normaluser@server: Permission denied (publickey)

According to `adduser` man page:

> The --disabled-password option will not set a password, but login is still possible (for example with SSH RSA keys).

Not being sure how ssh keys should be generated in this instance, I `sudo su` to the `normaluser` account and generated keys using `ssh-keygen`.

I've then tried to use the public and the private key file (copied to my local machine) to then ssh into the remote machine as `normaluser`, specifying the appropriate key file with `ssh -i` but I am still getting `access denied (publickey)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your key is added to /home/normaluser/.ssh/authorized_keys
Authorized keys are **per user**, meaning that just because a key can be used to log into another user doesn't mean you can use it to log in as any user.

Comment: Awesome first answer @Oreoezi

Comment: Thank you. Hope this helped.